# CSS: print on single page

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a fairly large image, and I'd rather have it scaled (proportionally) than chopped off at the end of the first page and continued on the next page. I want the whole page printed on one sheet of paper: intro text, large image, and footer text. How do I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print {
    @page {
        max-height: 95%; 
        max-width: 95%;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
/*
    html, body {
        max-height: 95%;
        max-width: 95%;
    }
    svg {
        max-width: 95%;
        max-height: 95%;
    }
*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Print test</h1>
<p>text before</p>
<svg width="500" height="1000">
    <rect width="500" height="1000"/>
</svg>
<p>text after</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried setting the page's `max-width` and `max-height` (and `with` and `height`), but Firefox still breaks in the image.

`page-break-inside: avoid` is contra productive: without it, I get 2 pages, with it I get 3 pages (text before the image on its own page, then most of the image, then the rest). I guess the browser tries to honor that rule and makes more room on the 2nd page by pushing the text before the image to the 1st page.

I am reluctant to use `scale(...)` as not all pages have such large images, and I don't want to enlarge an image that easily fits the page. I do know the image's dimensions in pixels, though.

How can I get the browser to scale the page as needed and print the whole page on one sheet of paper?